# Connect router to another wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking

Which are the necessary conditions in order to have a wireless router able to connect to another wireless router?

My setup:
- router A to be connected to the IPS using an wired ADSL service.
- router A to provide wired & wireless internet access in the house.
- router B to connect to router A using a wireless connection.
- router B to provide internet access only to computers which are wired to it.

It is possible scenario from above? Which are the technical requirements for the routers in order to achieve that connectivity?

Answer (score 2):

For access point to connect A >< B you would need something called a "[wireless bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_bridge)". A would be connected to the internet and "bridged" to B, while devices would be wired to B.

Depending (as far as I know) on the devices you are using, they can only be used as a bridge or a access point seprately, not at the same time, although if you look for a high-price router/modem then you might be able to do what you are after.

Comment: on a A><B wireless bridge, router A cannot provide wired services anymore? DHCP for example?

Comment: It probably depends on the make/model of the router/device what services it can perform, but I would expect that A would be able to provide a DHCP server scope and similar functions (for example be on 192.168.2.1) and then B would be on 192.168.2.2 with the scope from A distributing 192.168.2.5-2.255 or similar.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to be able to access an exiting wireless network, but I do not think router allow that (or depends). I read [this](http://www.wirelessforums.org/alt-internet-wireless/how-connect-wireless-router-wireless-router-3119.html) which say you need a router that implements [Wireless Distribution System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Distribution_System) to do that.

On an other side, the router B needs to have its default gateway configure to the IP of router A to be able to relay the packets.

Answer (score 2):

yup as mentioned by tombull89 and M'vy, you need either a WDS or Wireless Bridge. most consumer routers will not support either of those. but you can flash your router using custom firmwares. i'm using DD-WRT which has wireless bridging features.