# Connect a wireless router to another wireless router

Tags: router, wireless-bridge

I’m a complete novice when it comes to networking.

I have two wireless routers, let's call them “A” (a DIR-300 A1) and “B” (a DIR-600).

“A” is connected directly to a DSL connection. I want to connect B wirelessly to A and then connect my TV to B with a cable, similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/262299/connect-router-to-another-wireless-router).

Is it possible to do it with the hardware I have? If so, is there *any* place with a beginner-level tutorial on this? I’ve tried figuring this out and it is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup with a DIR-300 connected to my computer and something else connected to the Internet (I don't have physical access to that device).

The stock firmware of the DIR-300 does not do this, as far as I could tell (and jdh tells us), but I flashed it with [DD-WRT](https://www.dd-wrt.com/) ([instructions](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/D-Link_DIR-300_rev_A), probably voids any kind of warranty). Type in "dir-300" [here](https://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) for the files.

Then the setup was fairly straightforward in the web interface to set it up as a wireless Client rather than an AP, and fill in the network details.

#### PS

The way around you specified was the opposite of what I have, but flashing instructions for the DIR-600 seem to be [here](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/D-Link_DIR-600_/_300vB).

Comment: This is correct. The factory firmware cannot do this (it's an odd omission) but open source firmware can. DD-WRT can do it in client bridge mode.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it looks like these two DLink routers do not support wireless bridging.
The best you can hope for, is to run a cable from A to B, turn off DHCP (if the router's firmware allows it?). But if you don't need the extra ports of Router B, or its extended wireless range, (and your only goal is to connect the tv) than this doesn't help and your only choice is to run a lan cable from A to the TV. 
Its probably easier to connect a USB wireless ethernet adapter to the TV for less than the cost of a new router.